# Set micronaut environment variable in runtime

Tags: java, micronaut

I want to set micronaut application name programatically, something like

```
@Singleton
public class AppNameInitializer {
    @Inject
    public void initAppName(Environment env) {
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(env.getActiveNames()) ){
            // i want to set property 'micronaut.application.name' to app-with-profiles
        } else {
            // i want to set property 'micronaut.application.name' to app-without-profiles
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that? I tried that using

```
@Singleton
public class AppNameInitializer {
    @Inject
    public void initAppName(Environment env) {
        String propertyLowercase = "micronaut.application.name";
        // for some reason
        String propertyUppercase = "MICRONAUT_APPLICATION_NAME";
        String appNameWithProfiles = "app-with-profiles";
        String appNameWithoutProfiles = "app-without-profiles";
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(env.getActiveNames()) ){
            System.setProperty(propertyLowercase, appNameWithProfiles);
            System.setProperty(propertyUppercase, appNameWithProfiles);
        } else {
            System.setProperty(propertyLowercase, appNameWithoutProfiles);
            System.setProperty(propertyUppercase, appNameWithoutProfiles);
        }
    }
}
```

That didn't work

Answer (score 2):

Since the application is defined in the `application.yml` there is no need to add additional code. But you could introduce an environment variable like in this example:

```yaml
micronaut:
  application:
    name: "${MY_APP_NAME:default-name}"
```

In the example above you can use the environment variable `MY_APP_NAME` to set the application name. If the env variable is not set, the application will use the default name `default-name`.